# Easy way to delete all documents in cosmosdb with mongodb api

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

What is the easiest way to delete all documents in the container in cosmosdb with mongodb api? Can I do it directly from AZURE portal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

(1) by deleting existing container and recreating a new container with same name

(2) by setting the [TTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/time-to-live). You can se the time to live of the container to 1 second. ETA for the deletion of documents will be depending on the number of documents and the throughput of Cosmos DB account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/mongodb-time-to-live